# Java - Serialize anonymous object

Tags: java, json, serialization

I want to serialize an anonymous object in Java but I always get null as a result of the serializing, Here is what i'm trying exactly:

```
public class User{
    private String login;
    private String password;
    private String email;

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void Serialize() throws ParseException, IOException {
        Serializable obj = new Serializable(){
            public final String login = getLogin();
            public final String email= getEmail();
        };
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(Home.url);
        StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").create().toJson(obj));
        System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(stringEntity));
        //Here I'm getting null as result
        //.......
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create an anonymous object to filter the fields which i dont like to send them to the server-side.
In c# serializing anonymous object to json worked fine for me, but in java I don't know why it doesn't work !

Answer (score 4):

It is not java.io.Serializable to blame, but your Json library!

From https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Finer-Points-with-Objects:

> Fields corresponding to the outer classes in  inner classes, **anonymous classes**, and local classes are ignored and **not included in serialization or deserialization**

Btw. you don't need "Serializables", "Objects" do it as well, but please use
**named**, not anonymous.